# c# Getting issue with adding sql data to list

Tags: c#, sql, list

It was a long time ago that I was working with C#. And im making a program that will take in 3 sql database tables and to save them in a list.

I followed a guide on how to handle this, but im not sure what is wrong with it.
Im getting an output of the data when i print it out, but 0 is going into my list.

Please help me out, and thanks in advance :)

Code:

```
List<Product> products = null;
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = @"";

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        cnn.Open();
        if (cnn != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
        }


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT data1.zip_code ZipCode, data1.order_date as OrderDate, data1.order_number as OrderNumber, data1.first_name as firstName, data1.last_name as lastName, data2.order_number as OrderNumb2Two, data2.sku_id as SkuID, data2.quantity as Quantity, data2.price as Price, data3.article_name as articleName, data3.[weight] as Weight FROM data1,data2,data3", cnn);


 var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        /*
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {

            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["ZipCode"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["OrderDate"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["OrderNumber"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["firstName"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["lastName"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["SkuID"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["Quantity"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["Price"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["articleName"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dataReader["Weight"].ToString());
        }*/

        products = GetList<Product>(dataReader);

        
        if(products != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(products);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(products);
        }
        foreach(object o in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }

        cnn.Close();

    }

public class Product
    {
        public int SkuID { get; set; }
        public Int32 Quantity { get; set; }
        public Int32 Weight { get; set; }
        public Int32 Price { get; set; }
        public Int64 OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public Int64 OrderNumb2Two { get; set; }
        public string articleName { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }

public static List<T> GetList<T>(IDataReader reader)
        {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
         
            var type = typeof(T);
            T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var propType = prop.PropertyType;
                prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(reader[prop.Name].ToString(), propType));
                //Console.WriteLine(Convert.ChangeType(reader[prop.Name].ToString(), propType));
                
               
            }
            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
```

Comment: Consider using a mapping library like Dapper. Also you need `using` on your connection, command and reader objects. And consider using a verbatim string `@""` so that you can embed newlines and make the SQL more readable

Comment: side-note: the `if (cnn != null)` is redundant since you use the connection one line before, so ou would get a NRF if it was null. In other words, it's always != null.

Comment: You should really clean up your SQL, cross joining 3 tables just creates a matrix of all possible values, this is not usable data, you really should identify the relationship between the tables.

Comment: You use `Convert.ChangeType(reader[prop.Name].ToString(), propType))`. Why you convert the object to string and then you assign it to the property which might have a different type like `int`? Just use `Convert.ChangeType(reader[prop.Name], propType))`. You should also filter the properties by those which exist in the reader. Otherwise you set values for properties which don't exist. You can do this before the loop, this is also much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other issues, as stated in the comments, [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0) is not appropriate usage in this specific case. `ChangeType` does not actually *mutate* the value at all, it only returns the object that is equivalent to the requested type, if the original object is already in an equivalent type.

> Read more on [Type Conversion in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/type-conversion)

In this case, you should be experiencing this error:

```
Run-time exception (line 103): Input string was not in a correct format.

Stack Trace:

[System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
   at Program.GetList[T](IDataReader reader) :line 103
   at Program.Main() :line 45
```

The key here is that you have deliberately converted the values into `string`, and `string` types are not equivalent to value types like `int` and `DateTime`.

If you want to use `ChangeType` then you need preserve the `DbType` by using `GetValue`:

```
prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(prop. Name)), propType));
```

or we can break that down to be more obvious:

```
int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(prop. Name);
object columnValue = reader.GetValue(columnIndex);
prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(columnValue, propType));
```

> **NOTE:** This is still only going to work if you make sure that the type in the database is *equivalent* to the type in the corresponding property on the object you are trying to set.
>
> > We would usually store *postal* or *zip* codes in a database using a *character* based type, **NOT** an integer type, as this will preserve leading zeros and many jurisdictions use non-numeric characters for some of their postal codes... but that is another discussion, the point is, `Convert.ChangeType()` will still fail if the types are not correct.

This fiddle shows a simple example where `Convert.ChangeType()` will still fail: https://dotnetfiddle.net/j0ArmN

So does this, even `Int16` is not equivalent to `Int32`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rm2XqO

```
Run-time exception (line 114): cannot use ChangeType to convert 'Quantity': System.Int16 => System.Int32 (Value=12)
```

In fact a integer column for Price is also unusual, prices are commonly stored as *decimal* and as demonstrated here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yaxLpk Decimal (obviously) can't be *changed* or *converted* to an integer without loss of information:

```
Run-time exception (line 114): cannot use ChangeType to convert 'Price': System.Decimal => System.Int32 (Value=14.0000)
```

This is a working fiddle to show that the logic can work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xYBLr3

---

There are of course many *better* ways to achieve the same simple outcomes, consider [TableAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) or [Linq to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/linq-to-sql-tools-in-visual-studio2?view=vs-2022) or a fully featured ORM like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/entity-data-model-tools-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) instead of trying to do everything from first principals.

This is a minimal EF6 Implementation that uses serialization techniques to read the data into the expected type: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TVxGfw